# Additional initializer in a sub class overrides an initializer in the super class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class `XYZObject` which inherits from `ABCObject` with some initializers and methods:

```
class XYZObject: ABCObject {
    var name: String = "" 

    init(withName name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

class ABCObject{
    internal var jsonstore: JSON

    init(withJson newJson: JSON){
        jsonstore = newJson
    }
}
```

However, whenever I now call `XYZObject(withJson: jsonstuff)` Swift gives me the error:  `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withJson:', expected 'withName:')`

I am fairly new to swift and iOS development. What did I miss here?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: What is `jsonstuff`?

Comment: A variable of type `JSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, a class does not inherit the initializers of its base class if you add a new initializer to the class.

If you wish to make `init(withJson:)` available in your `XYZObject` class, you need to add it:

```
override init(withJson newJson: JSON) {
    super.init(withJson:newJson)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. however, I am wondering why Swift asks me to add the `override` keyword, even though the initializers are actually not inherited.

Comment: I did forget the `override`. I fixed that. You need `override` because you are overriding the method, even if it is not explicitly made visible to the subclass. This is all covered in the "Initialization" chapter of the "The Swift Programming Language" book.

Comment: Even though the language doesn't *need* to require that you use `override`, like many things in Swift it's a good way to ensure that you know what you're doing. In this case, `override` ensures that the signature of the subclass's `init` is what you think it is, and that such a method does exist in the superclass. You'd get a syntax error if one of those weren't true. If Swift didn't require `override` there, you might inadvertently define a whole new initializer in the subclass.